# Accessing files in windows as Local site using FileZilla from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ip, ftp, filezilla

I'm using ubuntu. I've connected to a server of live site in remote site section of filezilla. I've to access code shared in another's IP which runs Windows at the Local Site of Filezilla. I've tried to enter the IP address such as

> 192.168.0.240, //192.168.0.240, \192.168.0.240 , smb://192.168.0.240

. I tried all these combination and a lot of others but nothing works. It pops the message

> /192.168.0.240' does not exist or cannot be accessed.

Whatever I try a forward slash is always prepended in the pop up.

Comment: Are you sure that is the server's IP and it's a public server? Normally 192.168.*.* is reserved for private use, not public internet access, so, unless the server is inside your own network it is not a public server or the address you have is not correct

Comment: Yes this is in my own network and I'm able to access files using filezilla from windows PC easily by writing //192.168.0.240 at the input field next to Local Site in Filezilla. It is where I've to modify code.